# Writing to a csvFile using two lists. How do i write each list to two different columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv

I can write the first list of items to go down the first column how i want it but im struggling to get the second list to write to the third[2] column in the csv file. This i what i currently have. This just writes the second list below the first as i have just repeated the action of the first list.

```
firstHalf = ["Dad", "Mom", "nan"]
secondHalf = ["Brother", "Sister", "Cousin"]
    with open('MyFile.csv', 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
        csv_app = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        for player in firstHalf:
            csv_app.writerow([player])
        for player1 in secondHalf:
            csv_app.writerow([player1])
```

This currently writes this to the csv file with all the elements of both list down the first[0] column. i want the first list down the first column but second list down the third column.

Iv played around this a few things but struggling to get it how i want in the csv file.

Comment: what is your expected output, what do you want in second column

Comment: Dad Mom Nan in the first column of the csv

Comment: and brother sister cousin in the third column

Comment: you want empty second column, tell me teh second column name ?

Comment: yeah i want an empty second column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) function.

```
firstHalf = ["Dad", "Mom", "nan"]
secondHalf = ["Brother", "Sister", "Cousin"]

with open('text.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    csv_app = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
    for one, two in zip(firstHalf, secondHalf):
        csv_app.writerow([one, None, two])
```

Mind, that your lists should be of the same length.

Comment: That works brilliantly thank you. Yes both lists are the same length.

Comment: but you dont want second column right ? @EthanVenencia

Comment: Oh god yeah haha forgot that. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I guess, you could use `None` value to fill it like it's your second column. Like `csv_app.writerow([one, None, two])`

Comment: Cant seem to get it working, when im including 'None' it does introduce an empty column but it only does one row.

Comment: Just checked, works fine. Can you provide more details?

Comment: Is "csv_app.writerow([one, None, two])" that the only place you included "None"?

Comment: if i include None where you suggested it simply writes 1 row to the csv file. In the correct format but just 1 row.

Comment: ah, you did that :) Look up the post, I eddited my answer

Comment: Dad,,Brother
Mom,,Sister
nan,,Cousin

Comment: This is an output that I get

Comment: iv done exactly what you put. Still getting 1 row. Same as before?